# Open bounty message appears after voting

Tags: feature-request, bug

When voting to close a question with an open bounty, the user is walked through the wizard (to determine the close reason), and only after choosing the appropriate close reason (e.g. duplicate-of) and clicking *close*, a message appears stating that:

> This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed

I couldn't decide if it's a bug or a feature-request, but it needs a resolution IMHO; the message should pop up the minute the user clicks the close link at the bottom (or disable the close-vote upfront for bounty questions altogether).

Comment: right, sorry. closing..

Comment: Wait ... this is marked as a duplicate of a question that has received 12 down-votes and no other acceptable answer? Perhaps I'm missing the *point* of "question is a duplicate of* ... I had assumed that a negative-sum vote score would have an influence against "effective answer". This point needs to be addressed: *I can ask any question I want without risk of it being closed for being horribly-asked as long as I can throw some arbitrary reputation points as bounty.* I'm not a paranoid conspiracyist, but that sounds pretty bad (elitest?) to me.